# Prevent vs code to format Express JS code to newline

Tags: javascript, format, visual-studio-code

Vs code did this on format

```
app.get(
"/user/:id",
function(req, res, next) {
   if (req.params.id === "0") next("route");
   else next();
},
function(req, res, next) {
   res.send("regular");
}
);
```

and i need this

```
app.get("/user/:id",function(req, res, next) {
   if (req.params.id === "0") next("route");
   else next();
},
function(req, res, next) {
   res.send("regular");
}
);
```

I have tried this possible answer but not helpful

> "eslint.format.enable": false
>    "javascript.suggest.includeAutomaticOptionalChainCompletions": false,"

Comment: disable your linting extension or update the rule.

Comment: It is quite unusual to want to have the start of arguments 1 and 2 on the same line but the start of argument 3 on a different one.